# Find the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/(5)\times \mathbb{Z}/(5)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Find the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/(5)\times \mathbb{Z}/(5)$ including trivial subgroups.

My Work:

If we consider $\mathbb{Z}/(5)$ then the only subgroups are trivial subgroups. But how can we find it for $\mathbb{Z}/(5)\times \mathbb{Z}/(5)$? Is their a particular Proposition, Theorem or corollary which can be used here? Please help.

Comment: Hint: If the subgroup is neither trivial nor the entire group, what order must it have?

Comment: It must be $5$ for this example

Comment: Great. Now, how do we find a subgroup of order 5?

Comment: I don't have an idea how to find it. But I am sure that subgroup must be normal in $\mathbb{Z}/(5)\times \mathbb{Z}/(5)$

Comment: Note that they are cyclic, so it suffices to find elements of order 5 and find out which of those give the same subgroups.

Comment: So, if I suppose there are $n$ no.of such subgroups, then there are $n$ elements whose order is $5$. Afterwards what can I do?

Comment: See part $(b)$ in my solution here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087975/117021

Comment: How many elements of order 5 are there in such a subgroup? How many elements will distinct subgroups have in common?

Comment: Ok, so there are $4n$ no. of elements of order $5$ in this group $\mathbb{Z}/(5)\times \mathbb{Z}/(5)$.

Comment: So, $4n=24$, hence $n=6$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group has the identity plus $24$ elements of order $5$. When you have a subgroup of order $5$, you have a collection of the identity, plus four of the other $24$ elements. So do you see how the $24$ elements are partitioned?

Comment: How do you say that those $24$ elements have order $5$?

Comment: Ok got it thanks.